# What does gl.glClearColor do?

Tags: java, android, graphics, opengl-es

```
gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f);
```

How do I read it? As:

```
set clear color
```

or

```
clear the color
```

?

Comment: If you're new here, don't forget about the accept and up-vote functionalities.

Answer (score 24):

@Mikola's answer is correct, but I'll emphasize it a bit: calling `glClearColor` does *not* clear anything. It usually takes the value you've specified, and writes it to a register on the graphics card. Only later when you call `glClear`, with `COLOR_BUFFER_BIT`, does the buffer actually get cleared to the color you specified.

Answer (score 9):

It sets the background color for when you call glClear.

Relevant man pages:

http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glClear.xml

http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glClearColor.xml